# How to measure the build execution time?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, powershell-2.0, msbuild-4.0

I am having build script in msbuild which will be invoked by powershell.

Build log file would look like this.

Build started 12/19/2011 2:01:54 PM.

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.28

At starting point it will specify the build execution initiated time and the end it will say Time elapsed.

I would like to find the execution time using powershell or msbuild. How can i add all the time elapsed value or find the difference between last build started occurrence with first build occurrence?

As it is in log file , i don't know how to retrieve this and measure.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Measure CmdLet in powershell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176899.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Measure-Commmand` to see how long is your build process. Here's an example:

```
Measure-Command { ./build.ps1 }
```

The output on my machine was:

```
PS D:\> Measure-Command { ./build.ps1 }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 6
Milliseconds      : 443
Ticks             : 64439301
TotalDays         : 7.45825243055556E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00178998058333333
TotalMinutes      : 0.107398835
TotalSeconds      : 6.4439301
TotalMilliseconds : 6443.9301
```

Comment: Msbuild itself will provide measurement as time elapsed. My script has many msbuild commands and i want to know collective measure. Your answer meant for one msbuild command

Comment: The execution time of the script itself can be measured. Show me how you invoke your script.

Comment: You can run PowerShell from within PowerShell, just wrap the command within the braces. I am updating my answer to show you what I ran and it's output.

Comment: What was I thinking...there's no need to run PowerShell from within PowerShell. You can just run your build script within the Measure-Command: Measure-Command { ./build.ps1 }. I have updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that if you use Measure-Command {  }, it will consume the console output of your build. So any output would be gone.

A less intrusive way of doing this is by simply doing a subtraction of Get-Date values. For example, here would be your build.ps1 script:

```
$before = Get-Date
<your build command line>
$after = Get-Date

$time = $after - $before
$buildTime = "`nBuild finished in ";
if ($time.Minutes -gt 0)
{
    $buildTime += "{0} minute(s) " -f $time.Minutes;
}

$buildTime += "{0} second(s)" -f $time.Seconds;
```

Comment: This is what I would do, though I would proabably just format the datetime string like "{0} minutes {1} seconds" -f, $time.minutes, $time.seconds to avoid any complicated if statements.